# Web Browsers can connect to WebDAV directory, but Cadaver and File Browsers cannot connect on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2

I enabled WebDav module in my apache web server on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I can connect to my WebDav directory over web browsers from different machines with digest authentication method. But I cannot connect WebDav directory with cadaver client from different machines as with the following examples below:

cadaver http://172.16.3.72/webdav/

Output:

```
  Could not open collection:
  403 Forbidden
  dav:/webdav/?
```

Or

cadaver http://alex@172.16.3.72/webdav/

Output:

```
  Could not open collection:
  403 Forbidden
  dav:/webdav/?
```

Or

cadaver dav://172.16.3.72:80/webdav/

Output:

```
  Could not open collection:
  403 Forbidden
  dav:/webdav/?
```

Or

cadaver dav://alex@172.16.3.72:80/webdav/

Output:

```
  Could not open collection:
  403 Forbidden
  dav:/webdav/?
```

As you see, cadaver doesn't prompt me to login credentials and gives 403 Forbidden error.

And also File Browsers cannot access my WebDav Directory. When I enter the following url into File Browser -> Connect to Server dialog box, Ubuntu dialog box gives the following error permanently:

dav://172.16.3.72/webdav

Output:

```
 Oops! Something went wrong.
 Unhandled error message. Http Error: Forbidden
```

or

dav://172.16.3.72:80/webdav

Output:

```
 Oops! Something went wrong.
 Unhandled error message. Http Error: Forbidden
```

or

dav://alex@172.16.3.72/webdav

Output:

```
 Oops! Something went wrong.
 Unhandled error message. Http Error: Forbidden
```

or

dav://alex@172.16.3.72:80/webdav

Output:

```
 Oops! Something went wrong.
 Unhandled error message. Http Error: Forbidden
```

Windows File Browsers gives the following error:

```
 Windows cannot access htp://1722.16.3.72/webdav
```

All this errors are valid for just webdav client called cadaver and File Browsers. I can access my WebDav directory over web browsers from linux and windows systems. What is the problem for cadaver and File Browsers? Any idea?

Note: Firewall (ufw) of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, which contains my apache server and webdav module, was disable while connection tests were carried out .

Comment: I'm not sure but this seems like an issue with the `cadaver` client and not on the Ubuntu server. I've just checked the [manual for cadaver](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/cadaver.1.html#contenttoc5) on Ubuntu, and it seems to need a `~/.netrc` file which would contain login information when you are connecting to a server that requires authentication. Maybe it has the same requirement on Windows. What you can also try is adding the password in the URL and see if that works `username:password@domain:port`.

Comment: When I tried to username:password usage,  again fail. Same result (403 Forbidden error) occured.

Comment: For me it was the mod_security plugin that blocked something. Check your error.log file. There you should find the reason for your 403 forbidden error. However you should not post your IP address here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that in my apache2.conf configuration file, there is a restriction which I included before about allowed http methods. I removed it and tried again to connect WebDav server with cadaver. Then finally cadaver will prompt me to login credentials. So problem is fixed.

Comment: can you tell me more detail What restriction did you included? I face same problem with CWP

Comment: In apache2.conf, there is the following conf snippet:

<Location />
   <LimitExcept HEAD GET POST>
      order deny,allow
      deny from all
   </LimitExcept>
</Location>

It disables http methods which the webdav introduces. Because of this I commented out this conf snippet and problem has gone.